# How can you switch between "Debugger" and "Deployment | Output" tabs in IntelliJ Debug using the keyboard?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to avoid using the mouse as much as possible - this is one thing I can't figure out how to do.

How can you switch between "Debugger" and "Deployment | Output" tabs in IntelliJ Debug using the keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's supposed to work via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>, but [doesn't work because of the bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-68994). Please watch/vote.

Comment: This is still a bug in version 10.5.2 - vote for this issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-63780

Comment: Switching between "Debugger" and "Server" now works... on OSX it's CTRL-left/right, though. What I'm after is a keyboard shortcut to switch between multiple servers!